# Rails 6.1 Scope merge/join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Can anyone point me to documentation that would explain how to do a merged scope in Rails 6.1?

Before 6.1 the following worked:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventories, dependent: :destroy
  scope :available, -> { joins(:inventories).merge(Inventory.available).group('products.id') }
```

(giving all products with a positive inventory value)

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
  scope :available, -> { where('number_available > 0') }
```

Now, I get the following error:

*ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))*

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the scope? A similar scope works fine on my end.

Comment: What's the complete error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error while updating from Rails 6.0 to 6.1.

I solved it by upgrading the `ransack` gem to a version >= 2.4.0:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'ransack', '~> 2.4.0'
```

Older versions of ransack gem are incompatible with Rails 6.1. Here is the pull request that added support to Rails 6.1:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/1172